# How to configure my vim to help me find the definition of terms?

Tags: vim

For example, when I encounter:

```
funcMiracle (argMagic);
```

I want to press a button, and woosh, I immediately jump to the definition of funcMiracle, regardless of it is in the current file or not.

Answer (score 3):

Install *exuberant ctags* on your machine. Then, from the command line, in your project root:

```
ctags -R
```

Pressing `ctrl-[` in Vim will then jump to the definition of the symbol. After the jump, `ctrl-T` will take you back where you just came from.

Comment: The question is, though it can help me find any function in *my* project, it won't automatically find the external functions that I probably linked from a header file, for example, the definition of fgets() in stdio.h.

Comment: Here's a guide to setting up ctags for external libraries: http://piao-tech.blogspot.com/2008/10/make-vim-and-ctag-play-nice-together.html

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Since I read your comment:

> The question is, though it can help me find any function in my project, it won't automatically find the external functions that I probably linked from a header file, for example, the definition of fgets() in stdio.h

Have a look at

- <kbd>C-[</kbd><kbd>C-I</kbd> for include file search
- <kbd>C-[</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> for and definition lookup
- <kbd>Shift-K</kbd> opens up the man page for the identifier under the cursor (e.g. `fgets` :)

With the [man.vim script](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ManPageView) you can also summon the manpage inside a Vim buffer for easy copy/paste, highlighting, crossreference like with `helptags` etc. Key: <kbd>Leader-K</kbd>

Once again, `:he ^[^I` etc. are good pointers for more help/details

---

#### Tags on external projects

You can generate tags for an external project (say, linux headers) using `ctags` as shown earlier (below). It then a matter of letting Vim know where your tags are:

```
:se tags+=/usr/src/linux/tags
```

Note the **`+=`**: Vim can handle multiple tags files at once

---

The standard approach

1. install (if you haven't), ctags
2. `:!ctags %` (or for recursive whole folder etc `:!ctags -R %:h` or `:!ctags **/*.c` etc)
3. use tags (<kbd>C-]</kbd> or Ctrl-MouseButton, see `:help tags` for complete reference)

You can integrate the building of tags in your makefile if you have one. Exuberant ctags is highly configurable; I routinely use

```
ctags --exclude=packagedir -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q
```

for use with C++, but it supports many many languages out of the box with zero configuration.

Comment: I hope I understood your question a bit better now